# Connecting signal returning object to slot without arguments

Tags: c++, qt

I have `QTablewidget` with `QDateEdit` widget in every row. I want to know which widget was edited by the user. What I did worked in similar situation with `QComboBox` widgets:

```
qint32 row = 0;
mapper = new QSignalMapper(this); //QFrame
for (Object const& o : o_list) {
    tableWidget->setRowCount(row + 1);
    QDateEdit * date = new QDateEdit(o.date); //QDate
    date->setProperty(r, row); //const * char('r')
    connect(date, &QDateEdit::dateChanged, mapper, &QSignalMapper::map);
    mapper->setMapping(date, row);
    tableWidget->setCellWidget(row, 0, date);
    i++;
}
connect(mapper, SIGNAL(mapped(int)), this, SLOT(myon_dateEdit_dateChanged(int)));
```

The only problem is that I can't connect `QDateEdit::dateChanged(QDate)` with `QSignalMapper::map()` because it doesn't want any argument (I had no problem like this for QComboBox as there is argumentless signal). I don't need QDate argument because while I know the position of the widget - I can check the date later. Any fast solution to this?

Edit: I have `QFrame::eventFilter` installed on the `QDateEdit` anyway because I need to change row selection for `QTableWidget` if `QDateEdit` was edited so I thought I could use it instead... but `QEvent::ModifiedChange` doesn't work for that and I don't know what to use...

Comment: *I can't connect QDateEdit::dateChanged(QDate) with QSignalMapper::map() because it doesn't want any argument.* This shouldn't be a problem: [`The signature of a signal must match the signature of the receiving slot. (In fact a slot may have a shorter signature than the signal it receives because it can ignore extra arguments.)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html#signals-and-slots)

Comment: @thuga with new connect I have "no matching funtion to call" (my bad to write this one in the example because there are two map functions and I didn't pick any :P) error and with the old one the mapper (and the whole application) was crashing inside some mapper's functions (no human-readable errors, just some random (for me) hex data :P)... I will not add the whole code again, the point is it's working with kiss-o-matic's approach and I needed it quick. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remember doing something a while back w/ a signalMapper, but in the end I prefer this:

```
connect( date, SIGNAL( dateChanged( int ) ), this, SLOT( handleDateChange( int ) ) );

void myObject::handleDateChanged( int ) {
    QDateEdit* changedEdit = static_cast<QDateEdit*>( sender() );
    // changedEdit is the one that changed 
}
```

You will need to keep track of which QDateEdit is which.  I'm usually keeping my widgets in some sort of container anyway for other reasons, so doing the above results in much less code complexity for me.

Comment: Use [`qobject_cast`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#qobject_cast) when casting `QObject` types (or its subclasses). This way you can check if the cast worked.

Comment: it's working, I wish I knew this before. :) @thuga I did, thank you too.

Comment: Thanks, thuga.  I assumed there was a more elegant way. ;)  

Glad you got it working, smsware.